# How to convert dates pulled from IMPORTXML to actual dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm importing a 45-day weather forecast from
https://weather.interia.com/long-term-forecast-chicago,cId,49700

The dates are listing like so:

```
1.11
2.11
3.11
4.11
5.11
6.11
7.11
8.11
9.11
10.11
11.11
12.11
13.11
14.11
15.11
16.11
17.11
18.11
```

How can I convert these to actual dates? `TO_DATE` hasn't worked.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(
 "https://weather.interia.com/long-term-forecast-chicago,cId,49700", 
 "//span[@class='date']"), "."),,2), INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(
 "https://weather.interia.com/long-term-forecast-chicago,cId,49700", 
 "//span[@class='date']"), "."),,1)))
```

[image: 0]